# Can't Turn on Windows Defender - Error code 8050800d

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, windows-defender

My friend using an HP pavilion G, running Win7 64 bit version.  Recently had to restore to factory defaults, due to unstable operating environment.  Reinstalled all updates, to date.
Using Windows Defender.

He started a download while getting an error message in action center. He can run Windows defender, He can even operate a scan.  But if he go into the Action Center, and click on the "turn on now" button,receive the error code message above.

Is the problem with Windows Defender, or did some other update shut off the program in order to successfully download the program update and "forget" to turn it back on?

Maybe others have had this problem and know of some way to fix it.

thanks advance....

Answer (score -1):

This may be caused by interference from another similar-purpose program. Try temporarily uninstalling any other security/malware scanning software, rebooting, and trying again.

See a more authoritative answer here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/microsoft-security-essential-scan-error-mesage-0-x/0edb0a1b-a11c-47f5-ad9f-018881f066c1

*(Yes, the link refers to Microsoft Security Essentials, but please note that they share the same code base--Windows Defender is the replacement for MSE, so it's basically a branding difference. The same diagnosis should apply.)*

Also, if you haven't already, try running a Quick Scan **to completion** and then waiting a few minutes after it completes. This apparently might allow it to fix/re-enable itself.

Finally, another "authoritative" discussion on this specific issue (mentioning Windows Defender specifically), unfortunately with no clear resolution:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning/cant-turn-on-windows-defender-error-code-8050800d/eb104282-40d5-43aa-83b9-c347608a2fd2

**Please post a comment** if any of these solutions work or don't work (especially if you cast a downvote), and I will update the answer.